# Are user story inputs and outputs the same as acceptance criteria?

Tags: agile, user-story

In one of his books, Robert Martin provides an example of test-driven pair programming conversation while developing a Bowling Game Scorer in which one asks about user stories' inputs and outputs.

The inputs are throws and the outputs are scores.

So I realized I had never thought about a requirement's inputs and outputs (to my recollecting).

Are the outputs the acceptance criteria for the user stories?

In that case what are the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the outputs the acceptance criteria for the user stories?

No.

acceptance criteria are example "Known combinations of input/output"

- input: last 3 throws of a player
- output: score of last throw and/or of current score